# How to use apache storm tuple

Tags: java, tuples, apache-storm

I just began with Apache Storm. I read the tutorial and had a look into [examples](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter) My problem is that all example work with very simple tuples (often one filed with a string). The tuples are created inline (using new Values(...)). In my case i have tuples with many fields (5..100). So my question is how to implement such tuple with name and type (all primitive) for each field?

Are there any examples? (i think directly implementing "Tuple" isn't a good idea)

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternative to creating the tuple with all of the fields as a value is to just create a bean and pass that inside the tuple.

Given the following class:

```
public class DataBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // add more properties as necessary
    int id;
    String word;

    public DataBean(int id, String word) {
        setId(id);
        setWord(word);
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
}
```

Create and emit the DataBean in one bolt:

```
collector.emit(new Values(bean));
```

Get the DataBean in the destination bolt:

```
@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
    try {
        DataBean bean = (DataBean)tuple.getValue(0);
        // do your bolt processing with the bean
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("WordCountBolt error", e);
        collector.reportError(e);
    }       
}
```

Don't forget to make your bean serializable and register when you set up your topology:

```
Config stormConfig = new Config();
stormConfig.registerSerialization(DataBean.class);
// more stuff
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("MyTopologyName", stormConfig, builder.createTopology());
```

Disclaimer: Beans will work fine for shuffle grouping. If you need to do a `fieldsGrouping`, you should still use a primitive. For example, in the Word Count scenario, you need go group by word so you might emit:

```
collector.emit(new Values(word, bean));
```

Comment: this seems really a great alternative, but i wonder how or when to use tuples (it is one of storm's key concepts)?!

Comment: You're still using a tuple.. just passing an object instead of a primitive. If you have the same 100 fields to pass everytime, then I'd use a bean like I show above. If the fields you send each time varies a lot then maybe it wouldn't be as useful.

Comment: it is perfectly clear for me but i was curious how to use "real" tuple (something with multiple fields). but as it seems nobody is using it...

Comment: It seems there is some misunderstanding. You never create a Tuple object directly. The Value object is translated into a Tuple Type internally. Thus, if the output Value has multiple field, the tuple has multiple fields, too. Furthermore, Storm does not support type checking. Last but nut least, the disadvantages of the beans ideas, is that you cannot access the individual attributes using felds grouping connection pattern.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Very good point about the fieldsGrouping, I added a disclaimer to the bottom.

Comment: Your solution has the disadvantage of data duplication (and IMHO, it is somewhat unnatural). I added an own answer now... I implemented this pattern already. See here for details: https://github.com/mjsax/aeolus/tree/master/queries/lrb/src/main/java/de/hub/cs/dbis/lrb/types

Answer (score 8):

I would implement a custom tuple/value type as follows: Instead of using member variables to store the data, each attribute is mapped to a fixed index into the object list of the inherited `Values` types. This approach avoids the "field grouping" problem a regular Bean.

1. it in not required to add additional attributes for fields grouping (what is quite unnatural)
2. data duplication is avoided (reducing the number of shipped bytes)
3. it preserves the advantage of the beans pattern

An example for word count example would be something like this:

```
public class WordCountTuple extends Values {
    private final static long serialVersionUID = -4386109322233754497L;

    // attribute indexes
    /** The index of the word attribute. */
    public final static int WRD_IDX = 0;
    /** The index of the count attribute. */
    public final static int CNT_IDX = 1;

    // attribute names
    /** The name of the word attribute. */
    public final static String WRD_ATT = "word";
    /** The name of the count attribute. */
    public final static String CNT_ATT = "count";

    // required for serialization
    public WordCountTuple() {}

    public WordCountTuple(String word, int count) {
        super.add(WRD_IDX, word);
        super.add(CNT_IDX, count);
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return (String)super.get(WRD_IDX);
    }

    public void setWort(String word) {
        super.set(WRD_IDX, word);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return (Integer)super.get(CNT_IDX);
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        super.set(CNT_IDX, count);
    }

    public static Fields getSchema() {
        return new Fields(WRD_ATT, CNT_ATT);
    }
}
```

To avoid inconsistencies, `final static` variables for "word" and "count" attribute are used. Furthermore, a method `getSchema()` returns the implemented schema to be used to declare output streams in Spout/Bolt method `.declareOutputFields(...)`

For output tuples, this type can be used straight forward:

```
public MyOutBolt implements IRichBolt {

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        // some more processing
        String word = ...
        int cnt = ...
        collector.emit(new WordCountTuple(word, cnt));
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(WordCountTuple.getSchema());
    }

    // other methods omitted
}
```

For input tuples, I would suggest the following pattern:

```
public MyInBolt implements IRichBolt {
    // use a single instance for avoid GC trashing
    private final WordCountTuple input = new WordCountTuple();

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        this.input.clear();
        this.input.addAll(tuple.getValues());

        String word = input.getWord();
        int count = input.getCount();

        // do further processing
    }

    // other methods omitted
}
```

`MyOutBolt` and `MyInBolt` can be connected as follows:

```
TopologyBuilder b = ...
b.setBolt("out", new MyOutBolt());
b.setBolt("in", new MyInBolt()).fieldsGrouping("out", WordCountTuple.WRD_ATT);
```

Using fields grouping is straight forward, because `WordCountTuple` allows to access each attribute individually.

Comment: Thanks for this, at the moment i use the "accepted" approach but instead of fields i use an EnumMap. The Enum specifies the fields and type of fields. At the moment i am struggling on creating an abstract tuple but Enum can't be abstract so either i have to use a normal Map or i hav to live with some redundancy - if i have a solution i will post it here.

Comment: +1 I like this a lot. On question though... since OPs question was about managing a lot of fields, passing all the fields via the constructor wouldn't really be feasible. Plus the order in which you add objects to the Values array matters so maybe your no-arg constructor should initialize everything with nulls?

Comment: Added all fields via constructor is a matter of taste I guess. A `null` initialization would be a valid improvement I guess. However, for setters it is irrelevant, as they use index access. And regular `ArrayList` methods (`Values` inherits from that) must be used with care of course. Otherwise, you might mess up everything!

Comment: Interesting and insightful answer. Any idea how to implement this for List of custom objects?

Comment: What do you mean be "List of custom objects"?