# in storm, how to emit a List of primitives

Tags: java-7, apache-storm

I am using storm 0.10 
I have a List over which I iterate and then emit tuples

```
for (CustomObject o: List<CustomObject>) {
  collector.emit(STREAM_NAME, new Values(o.getFirst, o.getName, o.getAddress));
}
```

Instead of emitting mulitple tuples, I want to emit just a single tuple which would be a nested List, something like this,

the main question I have is pertaining serialization.  Reading the storm doc suggests that java serialization is expensive and that Storm use Kryo serialization. Additionally, regular java POJO classes ought not to be sent over the wire without kryo. So I am trying to send a `List<List<Objects>>`
as follows,

```
List<List<Object>> valueList = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
for (CustomObject o: List<CustomObject>) {
  v.add(new ArrayList<Object>{ 
    {
     add(o.getFirst);
     add( o.getName);
     add(o.getAddress);
    }
  });
}
collector.emit(STREAM_NAME, new Values(valueList));
```

So the question is - is this done by storm using Kryo?

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/32053795/98933

Answer (score 3):

You can simply emit your `List`,

```
collector.emit(new Values(listCustomObject));
```

and then when you read it back in the `bolt` like this,

```
List<CustomObject> listCustomObject = (List<CustomObject>) tuple.getValue(0);
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**: Indeed I forgot to mention that the object must be `Serializable`! In order to deal with the list, I'd do something like:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class CustomObjectList implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6877020084704724252L;

    public class CustomObject {
        ...
    }

    private final List<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}
```

**EDIT2**:  Since I was doing too many things by heart, I've done/tested a quick toy example by modifying the `ExclamationBolt` in the [storm starter ExaclamationTopology](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/starter/ExclamationTopology.java)

It looks like this.

```
package storm.starter;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;


public class ExclamationBolt extends BaseRichBolt{

    public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExclamationBolt.class);    


    public class CustomObject {
        private String word;

        public CustomObject(String word) {
            setWord(word);
        }

        public String getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        public void setWord(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

    }
    public class CustomObjectList implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6877020084704724252L;

        private final List<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

        public CustomObjectList() {
        }

        public List<CustomObject> getObjects() {
            return list;
        }

        public void addObject(CustomObject o) {
            list.add(o);
        }
    }

    OutputCollector _collector;

    public ExclamationBolt() {
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        _collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        String id = tuple.getSourceComponent();
        String word;
        if ("word".equals(id)) {
            word = tuple.getString(0);
        } else {
            CustomObjectList list = (CustomObjectList) tuple.getValue(0);
            word = list.getObjects().get(0).getWord();
        }
        word = word + "!!!";
        LOG.debug(word);
        CustomObjectList list = new CustomObjectList();
        list.addObject(new CustomObject(word));
        _collector.emit(tuple, new Values(list));
        _collector.ack(tuple);
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("word"));
    }


}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok, and I am not emitting custom object, since I don't want to deal with Kryo serialization. Does storm serialize List<> by default using kryo

Comment: Hi. Indeed I forgot to mention that the class should be Serializable. I'm updating the answer. I expect it to work with no problems with the code I've posted. Just let me know.

Comment: thanks, but as I understand java serialization, according to the docs , is extremely expensive and frowned upon. So I am trying to avoid that and the question is, by using List of "objects" [ primarily primitives and Strings], can I get around implementing anything explicitly and just relying on Storm to do the serialization using Kryo as it does for the the primitives.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I guess the only way would be to build a custom serializer for storm Kyro, but I've never done it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use KryoSerialization.

1. Implement `CustomObjectSerializer`:

   ```
   class CustomObjectSerializer extends Serializer<CustomObject> {  
     @Override
     public void write(final Kryo kryo,
                       final Output output,
                       final CustomObject cObject) {
       // do serialization
     }

     @Override
     public CustomObject read(final Kryo kryo,
                              final Input input,
                              final Class<CustomObject> aClass) {
       // do deserialization
     }
   }
   ```
2. register CustomObjectSerializer to Storm config: 
   `conf.registerSerialization(CustomObject.class,CustomObjectSerializer.class);`

Comment: the docs are quite sketchy on this. specifically are there any examples for , // do serialization ? on read and write ? This is what I was trying to avoid since it's not clear to me and sending a nested List<List>

Comment: As far as I know, you don't have to worry about nested list if the elements are serializable. If the CustomObject is serializable, Storm automatically serialises List<List<CustomObject>>.  How to serialize CustomObject depends on the implementation. Please take a look https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo.