# Emitting Custom Java Object as Tuple from Spout

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am new to Apache Storm. To understand it I was looking at Storm examples provided in the Storm tutorial (https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter)  .

In all the examples, we are emitting primitive types (String,int etc) as tuples.

In my use case I am having a Java object which I want to emit as tuple to bolts.

I am not sure how to do it. It seems I have to implement a custom Tuple producer to convert Java object to `Values`.

Can anyone provide me some example how to do that:

For ex my Java object is :

```
class Bean 
{
   int A;
   String B;
   Bean2 b;
   //setters and getters
}
```

and

```
class Bean2
{
    //Some Attributes
}
```

Now, in my `nextTuple()` method for Spout, I have an instance of a `Bean` object.

```
class Spout implements IRichSpout
{
    //...
    void nextTuple()
    {
        Bean b = queue.poll();//queue contains instances of Bean Object
        //How to convert this object to tuple and emit it as Tuples???
    }
}
```

How do I translate into `Tuple` and emit it and consume it through my bolt.

Comment: By the way. You should register your `Bean` in Kryo if you use approach one. (See updated answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Emit just a single attribute tuple that contains the `Bean`:

   ```
   class Spout implements IRichSpout {
       void nextTuple() {
           Bean b = queue.poll();
           collector.emit(new Values(b));
       }
   }
   ```

   This is the simplest approach, but has the disadvantage, that you cannot use the individual attributes in `fieldGrouping(...)` for consuming bolts. Furthermore, you should register `Bean` in Kryo for efficient (de)serialization:

   ```
   Config c = new Config();
   c.registerSerialization(Bean.class);
   StormSubmitter.submitTopology("name", c, builder.createTopology());
   ```
2. Emit each attribute individually:

   ```
   class Spout implements IRichSpout {
       void nextTuple() {
           Bean b = queue.poll();
           // of course, you can also un-nest Bean2
           collector.emit(new Values(b.getA(), b.getB(), b.getBean2()));
       }
   }
   ```

   This allows to use each attribute (or combination of attributes) in `fieldsGrouping(...)`. However, at the consumer, you need to retrieve each attribute individually and use your setter-methods to build a new `Bean` object.

As an alternative to the second approach, please see [How to use apache storm tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053795/how-to-use-apache-storm-tuple)

Comment: Thanks Matthias :) ..You rock :)

Comment: One question though , In the bolt if we have to emit a different object say BoltBean bb , then will this bean be also registered in the same conf object that will be used while submitting toplogy . Namely ,

Config c = new Config();
c.registerSerialization(Bean.class);
c.registerSerialization(BoltBean.class);
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("name", c, builder.createTopology());

Comment: Yes. There is just one global `Config` and you can register all custom types there.